# My user input isnt multplying my stored values

Tags: c

Im making a program that asked the user how many pennies nickels dimes and quarters they have then tells them how much money they have after. I wrote the program but I cant figure out how to make the user input multiply with the values.

Ive rewritten it but cant get it to work.

```
    float a, b, c, d, e;
    a = 0.01;
    b = 0.05;
    c = 0.10;
    d = 0.25;
    e = a+b+c+d;


     printf("How many pennies?");
     scanf("%f" , &a);


     printf("How many nickels?");
     scanf("%f", &b);


     printf("How many dimes?");
     scanf("%f", &c);

     printf("How many quarters?");
     scanf("%f", &d);

     printf("You have $ %f", e);

     return 0;
```

}

There isnt any error messages it just adds up the values I already gave to a,b,c and d.

Comment: Why are you reading the number of pennies, nickels, dimes, and quarters into `float`s? Are you expecting the user to input fractions of a coin?

Answer (score 0):

C is an imperative programming language, so you need to put your statements in the order you want them to happen. Also, you can't use the same variable for the number of coins as you do for the value of that kind of coin.

Comment: The user is supposed to enter the value of coins they have then its supposed to multiply with that change amount

Comment: I'm aware of that; it doesn't affect anything I said.

Comment: Ok my mistake so how would I multiply what the user input by the coin value?

Comment: @TariqHenderson Use the multiplication operator `*`.

Answer (score 0):

You are storing the numbers of each of the coins in the values of the coins, which overwrites those values.  You're also trying to add the values of the coins before you read the numbers of each of the coins.

You need to store the numbers of each of the coins separately and sum the values after you have read them.

```
float a, b, c, d;
a = 0.01;
b = 0.05;
c = 0.10;
d = 0.25;

int na = 0, nb = 0, nc = 0, nd = 0;



 printf("How many pennies?");
 scanf("%i" , &na);


 printf("How many nickels?");
 scanf("%i", &nb);


 printf("How many dimes?");
 scanf("%i", &nc);

 printf("How many quarters?");
 scanf("%i", &nd);

 printf("You have $ %.2f\n", (na * a) + (nb * b) + (nc * c) + (nd * d));
```

Note, you generally shouldn't use floating-point values to store monetary values (please see [what every computer scientist should know about floating-point](https://www.itu.dk/~sestoft/bachelor/IEEE754_article.pdf)).